# Scrollbar does not scroll to the top in tabpage

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, tabpage, toolstrip

I have a strange behavior with my tabPage. First of all - when initializing the Form I use following code:

```
 tabPage3.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
```

However it looks like this:

[scrollbar position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryD0g.png)

The white line in the image is a toolstrip, so the scrollbar just scrolls up to the bottom of the toolstrip.
Now when I put the line of code into the Paint event of the tabPage it works (the scrollbar is at the very top of my tabPage). However, I then can't move the scrollbar down anymore - it jumps back to the top each time I want to move it. I tried different conditions like setting a value when entering the tabpage or at the scroll event of the page to use the code just once in the paint event but then it results in the behavior like shown in the image.

How can I solve this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Paint event gets run *a lot*. Every time the control needs to be repainted. So code you put there gets executed frequently. If you have code in there that resets the position of the scrollbar, it will be impossible to scroll. Anyway, it should be completely unnecessary to "initialize" the value of a scrollbar to 0. That is the default position (at the top or all the way to the left, depending on the scrollbar's orientation).

Comment: Ok but why does this work correctly (depending on the position) when put in the paint event? how to achieve that the position of the scrollbar is on the very top of the toolstrip?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the onPaint event of your tabPage, you could use the Selectedindexchanged event of your tabControl. There you can set Scrollbarvalue to 0 each time TabPage 3 is shown. You Code would look something like that.

```
private void TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage3)
  {
    tabPage3.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This will result in the same behavior like shown in the Image.  It does not scroll to the top

Comment: Did you add TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged to the IndexChanged Event of your TabControl?

Comment: Yes I did. Same result. This is a strange behavior. The scrollbar simply gets blocked by the toolstrip. This works only with the paint event till now. And only if it gets triggered a lot. Is there a solution for this? I don't get it...